# Cannot declare activity in manifest

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-manifest

I am trying to open a file in Chrome and if I do not use the try/catch an error is shown

> "**unable to find explicit** activity class (com.android.browser/com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main); have you declared this activity in your **AndroidManifest.xml**?

I have not declared it and do not know how - can anybody help me please?

```
void deployChromeFile()
{
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Documents/Recipe73.htm");
    if(file.exists()){
        try {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            browserIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
            browserIntent.setType("multipart/related");
            browserIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");                                                      
            browserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Activity not found ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }
    else{Toast.makeText(this, "File does not exist ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
}
```

Comment: is in your phone is browser is installed

Comment: Yes it is installed and can use it

Comment: check his package name then try, i think u call wrong activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sidetracked by the error message rederring to the Manifest.  No declaration is required there for intents. Due to my lack of knowledge, I was confusing intent filters with intents. Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation has been changed, try this simple way,

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uri);
    intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it crashes on "no activity found to handle intent".  Do I need to make any changes to the manifest?

Comment: Is chorme browser installed in your phone, or you testing on emulator?

Comment: Try updated code, if Chrome is not installed then it will show chooser with available browsers in phone.

Comment: posting this so you are alerted

Comment: Chrome is installed and it works fine otherwise. I have tried your updated code and the above error is in LogVat

Comment: Okay let me check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115507/discussion-between-neo-and-kalininskaya).